# jq: filter nested array objects

Tags: jq

Here my documents:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9",
    "identifier": [
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "04374"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "INFP3"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "CBOU035"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de",
    "identifier": [
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "04376"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "INF07"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "S527918"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a1ea574c-438b-443c-ad87-d31d09d581f0",
    "identifier": [
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "08096"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "INF04"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:INVENTAT"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "5635132"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to filter `.identifier` where `system.value="urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT"`  or `system.value="urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"` and pick `.value.value`.

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9",
    "oid1": "04374",
    "oid2": "INFP3"
  },
  {
    "id": "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de",
    "oid1": "04376",
    "oid2": "INF07"
  },
  {
    "id": "a1ea574c-438b-443c-ad87-d31d09d581f0",
    "oid1": "08096",
    "oid2": "INF04"
  }
]
```

I've tried:

```
map(
    {
        id,
        oid1: select(.identifier?[]?.system.value == "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT") | .identifier[].value.value,
        oid2: select(.identifier?[]?.system.value == "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT") | .identifier[].value.value
    }
)
```

But output is not what I need: you can find it on [this jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/wmFEICeuoy).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `IN` to check for your query strings, and `with_entries` on an array to generate the indeces for the `oid` keys.

```sh
jq '
  map({id} + (.identifier | map(select(IN(.system.value; 
    "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT",
    "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"
  )).value.value) | with_entries(.key |= "oid\(. + 1)")))
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9",
    "oid1": "04374",
    "oid2": "INFP3"
  },
  {
    "id": "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de",
    "oid1": "04376",
    "oid2": "INF07"
  },
  {
    "id": "a1ea574c-438b-443c-ad87-d31d09d581f0",
    "oid1": "08096",
    "oid2": "INF04"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-1mQh1AppG)

Comment: Thanks  @pmf. How could I replace `oid#` with `up:` and `uab:`? I mean, what I exactly need would be `{id,ub,uab}` fields instead of `{id,oid1,oid2}`. I don't quite figure out how to adpat you approach to get this.

Comment: `with_entries(…)` calculates the keys dynamically (i.e. it'd go for `oid3`, `oid4` and so on if there are enough records). Replace it with the static `{ub:.[0], uab:.[1]}` and you always get just those to entries (and the id up front). [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eHA7QNUGnM)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `ruby` to do that:

```
ruby -r json -e '
def walk(x, filt)
    rtr=[]
    rep=["uab", "ub"]
    x.each{|e| 
        rd={"id"=>e["id"]}.merge(
        e["identifier"].
            filter{|ea| filt.include?(ea["system"]["value"])}.
            map.with_index(1){|di, i| ["#{rep[i%2]}", "#{di["value"]["value"]}"]}.to_h)
        rtr << rd       
        }
    rtr
end
    
data=JSON.parse($<.read)
puts walk(data, ["urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.91-INVENTAT", "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2-INVENTAT"]).to_json
' file
```

Prints:

```
[{"id":"3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9","ub":"04374","uab":"INFP3"},{"id":"0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de","ub":"04376","uab":"INF07"},{"id":"a1ea574c-438b-443c-ad87-d31d09d581f0","ub":"08096","uab":"INF04"}]
```